# C# System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache not getting in ORDER

Tags: c#, .net

My Code as below to insert some data to Cache

```
Cache.Insert("Key" + 1, "1", null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
Cache.Insert("Key" + 2, "2", null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
Cache.Insert("Key" + 3, "3", null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
```

After insert to cache, I will grab my data at another page , the problem that I facing is cant get back the data in insertion Order , for example I insert 1 , 2 and 3, when I grab from the cache I am not getting my expected result which is 1 ,2 and 3. In fact it is return the cache in a random order suck as 3, 1, and 2 . I know I can grab all cache and recreate my own dictionary base on key to order it , but that is not a good solution it might waste of process time thus I think that is not a good solution .

How should get the cache in ORDER of my insertion order.

My current code is as follow

```
IDictionaryEnumerator CacheEnum = Cache.GetEnumerator();
while (CacheEnum.MoveNext())
{
    try
    {
        string[] Data = CacheEnum.Value.ToString();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string exx = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're relying on the order of your data in the cache, then the way you're using the cache is fundamentally flawed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to ensure this type of order I would instead cache an array of your values under a single cache key. Instead of a cache entry per key.

That way you can make sure everything is ordered correctly upon retrieving it.

```
var myList = new List<string>(){"Val1","Val2"};

Cache.Insert("myValues", myList.OrderBy(v => v), null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
```

Comment: Thank you , but my data does not come in one time , Val2 will come after val1.

Comment: You can sort the list before putting it into cache, and even add to it  as you go